# Formative model identification problem using SEM

Tags: structural-equation-modeling

I have problem in identifying a formative structural equation model using AMOS.Does anyone have any suggestion for dealing with the identification problem in formative measurement models?

Comment: Can we elaborate a bit more here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really informative, but I would suggest that you check [Bollen and Davis (2009)](http://www.citeulike.org/user/ctacmo/article/6211958) paper on causal indicators (which is the sociology slang for the psychologist's formative indicators; being Ken Bollen's student, I find the psychology slang ugly ;) ).

Comment: Did you intend the "in *formative*" pun? ;) One even has further distinctions between "formative" causal indicators and composite indicators ([Bollen & Bauldry, 2011](http://dx.doi.org/10.1037/a0024448)). The terminology is not the hard part IMO, making a reasonable argument for which ways the arrows should be going is the hard part.